# Enable stats uri page in HAProxy tcp mode

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

Below is my haxproxy configuration. I am trying to enable stats page so that I can see the status of the servers. But after validating the file, getting a warning message as below and stats page is not shown after hitting the configured uri.

**'stats' statement ignored for frontend 'http-in' as it requires HTTP mode**

I am using haproxy version 1.8.x.

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log  global
   mode tcp
   option   tcplog
   timeout connect 120s
   timeout client  300s
   timeout server  180s

frontend http-in        
     bind *:443
     stats enable
     stats refresh 10s
     stats uri /haproxy?stats
     default_backend servers


backend servers
    
     balance    roundrobin
     server sec-server1 192.68.29.230:8080 check
     server sec-server2 192.68.29.229:8080 check
```

Please assist. can we not see the stats page in tcp mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below things and try

***global***

```
global
    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 666 level admin
    server-state-file /var/lib/haproxy/haproxy.state
```

***defaults***

```
defaults
    default-server init-addr last,libc,none
    load-server-state-from-file global
```

***frontend***

```
frontend  http-in
    bind *:443

    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port 1443


    default_backend             servers

    stats uri                   /hap?_stats
    stats auth                  haadm:username@pwd
    stats hide-version
    stats show-node
```